# Android Async onPostExecute doesn't get fired

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to Populate a `ListView` after getting data from a Database using `AsyncTask`. I'm populating the `ListView` through the `onPostExecute` method after the `AsyncTask` gets the data, however the `ListView` doesn't get populated even though the database returns data.

Calling the Data:

```
private void RefreshNewsFeed() {
        new NewsfeedTask().execute();
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
private class NewsfeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                final MobileServiceList<ActivityTable> result = activitiesTable.execute().get();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!(result.isEmpty())) {
                            for (ActivityTable item : result) {

                                final ActivityTable activity = new ActivityTable();
                                activity.setID(item.getId());
                                activity.setContent(item.getContent());
                                activity.setUserID(item.getUserID());
                                activity.setMedia(item.getMedia());
                                activity.setType((item.getType()));

                                Log.d("CHECK", activity.getType());

                                UserTable user = GetUser(item.getUserID());
                                activity.setUser(user);

                                activities.add(activity);
                                //activities is a globally declared List
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.e("CHECK", "Error in Activity Loading 1");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e("CHECK", "Error in Activity Loading 2");
                Log.e("CHECK", exception.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            //Populate ListView after the AsyncTask returns values

            ListView newsreel = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newsreel_list);
            NewsfeedAdapter adapter = new     NewsfeedAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.activity_newsfeed,activities);
            newsreel.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

However, the `ListView` doesn't get populated. The list is not empty, I checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `AsyncTask` a subclass of your Activity?  One thing to note, calling `runOnUiThread()` defeats the purpose of using an AsyncTask.

Comment: @DanielNugent yes it is a subclass. I've got a major problem: The listview populates itself with *placeholders* BEFORE the data is retrieved, that is why I wanted to add the Adapter call to the onPostExecute.. why is that happening? How can I wait till the data is retrieved before populating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are overriding the wrong function. onPostExecute(result) takes a result argument. Change to:

```
onPostExecute(Void v)
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your follow up question: doInBackground is on worker thread and it returns result to postexecute(..)

you are setting activities on the main thread by calling run :

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() { ..
```

You might not have the async task, since everything is being done on main thread. doInBackground executes the couple of statement then goes to postExecute (setting listView) and then the run() method (setting activities). Let activities set up be on worker thread i.e. remove run()

Comment: hmm this works but the listview populates itself with placeholders BEFORE the data is retrieved, that is why I wanted to add the Adapter call to the onPostExecute.. why is that happening? How can I wait till the data is retrieved before populating?

Comment: As per your code, activities is initialized with the data first and then listview is populated. PostExecute(result) is called after doInBackground(). If your list is not populating it must be because activities is empty. can you use debugger to check if all is well with activities

Comment: Activities are retrieved successfully mate. I logged each of them. The Listview seems to be populated FIRST before the completion of data retrieval. Very very weird.

Comment: edited. don't forget to accept if it answers your questions :)

Comment: So I have to call the adapter to populate the listview from the runOnUIThread you defined in the edited section? Just to be clear, I have to call the 'new NewsfeedTask().execute();' and then in the runOnUIThread, I have to call the population? Can you clarify that please :)

Comment: remove runonUIthread. doInBackground is executed on worker thread. activities will be initialized on worker thread. return to onPostExecute, which is on main thread to inflate the listview. Alternatively do all of this in sequence in a function on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Before your AsyncTask methods add `@Override`. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {..}
```

Edit: Also, your `onPostExecute()` method takes an argument which will be the object you return from `doInBackground()`. So, add this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
```

Comment: there is no function as onPostExecute()

Comment: Yeah, I typed my answer in a hurry. Thanks for the reminder(and the downvote).

Comment: I've got a major problem: The listview populates itself with **placeholders** BEFORE the data is retrieved, that is why I wanted to add the Adapter call to the onPostExecute.. why is that happening? How can I wait till the data is retrieved before populating?

Comment: Maybe you would want to show a ProgressBar while the data is loading and then hide the ProgressBar when the data loads successfully? There is also something called an Empty View which will be displayed if the List is empty. You can search for these options and use whatever you want.